# Scrapy writing to a file takes very long and writes only a portion of scraped text

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing to a csv file using scrapy. I have parsed the website I want to scrape and saved the contents in a item container

```
yield(self.post_item)
```

The forum that I am scraping is quite large. The code that scrapes and writes seems to be working fine but it is taking very long to write to a csv file. I am writing it using  `scrapy crawl posts -o file.csv`. I forced close the script that was running but the csv file is still writing new contents (very slowly tho).

What could be causing this and how can I get around this?

Edit: here is my spider

```
class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'posts'
    # allowed_domains = ['dcurbanmom.com']

    page_count = 1
    forum_count = 0

    #Create an item container to store all this data
    post_item = PostsItem()
    post_subject_answer = ""
    post_subject_first_post_date = ""
    post_subject_views = ""
    post_subject_last_message_date = ""
    total_post = 0
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.dcurbanmom.com/jforum/forums/show/32.page'
        # 'https://www.dcurbanmom.com/jforum/posts/list/643613.page'
    ]

    # Grabs the list of threads in the DCPS forum
    def parse(self, response):
        count = 0
        for next_forum in response.xpath('//span[@class="topictitle"]'):
            if(self.page_count > 10):
                return
            next_forum_link = next_forum.xpath('.//a/@href')
            next_forum_url = response.urljoin(next_forum_link.extract_first())
 
            answers = next_forum.xpath('.//ancestor::td[1]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()')
            self.post_subject_answer = answers.get()
            self.total_post += int(answers.get())
            
            first_post = next_forum.xpath('.//ancestor::td[1]/following-sibling::td[2]/span/text()')
            self.post_subject_first_post_date = first_post.get()

            views = next_forum.xpath('.//ancestor::td[1]/following-sibling::td[3]/span/text()')
            self.post_subject_views = views.get()

            last_message = next_forum.xpath('.//ancestor::td[1]/following-sibling::td[4]/span/text()')
            self.post_subject_last_message_date = last_message.get()

            yield scrapy.Request(url = next_forum_url, callback=self.parse_contents)
            
            count += 1
            self.forum_count += 1

        next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]//a[contains(text(),"►")]')
        if (len(next_page) > 0):
            next_page = next_page[0].xpath('./@href')
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page.extract_first())
            self.page_count += 1
            yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
                      
        print("Total discussions traversed: " + str(self.forum_count))
        print("Total pages traversed: " + str(self.page_count))
        print("Total posts scraped: ", self.total_post)
        
    #Parses individual discussion thread 
    def parse_contents(self, response):
        all_posts = response.xpath('//table[@class="forumline"]//tr')
        post_date = ""
        post_text = ""
        post_subject = ""
        post_author = ""
        urls = []
        href_links = {}
        for post in all_posts:
            #Extract the date from post info
            post_date_response = post.xpath('.//div[@class="postinfo"]//div[@class="date"]/text()').getall()
            if(len(post_date_response)>0):
                post_date = post_date_response[-1].strip()   
            
            #Extract the post subject
            post_subject_response = post.xpath('.//div[@class="postinfo"]//div[@class="subject"]//a/text()')
            if(len(post_subject_response)>0):
                post_subject = post_subject_response.extract_first() 
            
            author = post.xpath('.//span[@class="genmed"]/b/text()').get()
        
            if(author is not None):
                post_author = author

            post_text_response = post.xpath(".//div[@class='postbody']/br/following-sibling::text()[1] | .//div[@class='postbody']/br/following-sibling::a[1]/text() | .//div[@class='postbody']/text() | .//div[@class='postbody']/a/text()")
            
            if(len(post_text_response.getall())>0):
                post_text = "".join(re.sub('\r','',x) for x in post_text_response.getall()).strip()
                url_pattern = r'(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)'
                urls = re.finditer(url_pattern, post_text)
                url_list = [x.group() for x in urls]
            
            href_links_response = post.xpath(".//div[@class='postbody']//following-sibling::a[1] | .//div[@class='postbody']/a")

            if(len(href_links_response)>0):
                #Creat a list of texts inside the hyperlinked urls
                a_text_list = [x.xpath("./text()").extract_first() for x in href_links_response]

                #In the URL list (that was copied separatley by the poster), keep only the links that are not in the hyperlink
                url_in_message_only = [x for x in url_list if x not in a_text_list]
                
                href_links = [x.xpath("./@href").extract_first() for x in href_links_response]

            # Populate the item container
            if(bool(re.search(r'^\s*$', post_text))==False):
                self.post_item['post_date'] = post_date
                self.post_item['post_message'] = post_text
                self.post_item['post_subject'] = post_subject
                self.post_item['post_author'] = post_author
                self.post_item['post_hyperlinks'] = href_links
                self.post_item['post_non_hyperlinks'] = url_in_message_only
                self.post_item['post_subject_answers'] = self.post_subject_answer
                self.post_item['post_subject_first_post_date'] = self.post_subject_first_post_date
                self.post_item['post_subject_views'] = self.post_subject_views
                self.post_item['post_subject_last_message_date'] = self.post_subject_last_message_date
                
                post_date = ""
                post_text = ""
                post_subject = ""
                post_author = ""
                url_in_message_only = ""
                href_links = ""
                yield(self.post_item)  
        # Go to next page
        next_page = response.xpath('//div[@class="pagination"]//a[contains(text(),"►")]')
        if len(next_page) > 0:
            next_page = next_page[0].xpath('./@href')
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page.extract_first())
            yield scrapy.Request(url = next_page_url, callback=self.parse_contents)
```

And here is settings.py

```
# Scrapy settings for scraper project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'scraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scraper.spiders'

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'scraper (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
LOG_ENABLED = False

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32
#Wait 250ms between each request
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25 
# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'scraper.middlewares.ScraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'scraper.middlewares.ScraperDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'scraper.pipelines.ScraperPipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'

FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'

#Rotating proxies - by scrapy-rotating-proxies
# ROTATING_PROXY_LIST_PATH = 'http.txt'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    # ...
    # 'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 800,
    # 'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 800,
    # ...
}

RANDOM_UA_PER_PROXY = True
```

Comment: Could you please share the spider code and your settings.py

Comment: @MuratDemir I have added the spider and settings.py to my post

Comment: Facing the same issue here. were you able to find a way to make it faster? I somehow think it is slow because all threads are trying to write to one single csv file.